# Concurrent access to data on MVC .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, concurrency

I have a MVC web site that access a process list from database and select a "random" process so that the user can analyze. He can aprove or not that process and automatically receive another.

The problem is several users will do the process simultaneously and I need to block those processes that are already under review.

I can´t do that on database side, so must be an application solution and completely invisible to users...

How can I solve that problem?

--- Edit

One scenario will be : User get a process (the process is locked), than he "forgets" open or "closes" the browser.
So I need to unlock that process somehow.

Some ideas I had:

- Using MSMQ (Is that possible to put back a process when the user "forget" to finish the task?)
- Using a static ConcurrentBag on my webapp to keep the list of ids on review. (Will IIS recycle kill that list?)

Thanks

Comment: You could look into using a ConcurrentBag for that.

Comment: You could have another table that holds "pending for review", and when a process is selected add the ID to that table. When selecting processes, if the ID is in that table, then its already being reviewed and you need to select another one.

Comment: Ron, as I said on question, I can´t do that on database side...

Comment: In how many servers does that application run simultaneously?

Comment: At first only on one server (iis)

Comment: You can use static properties to lock the process as Ron suggested via Database if yo use the same technique using static properties that will also work on application level

Comment: You could also apply what I said to a locking file stored on the server, although its going to be a lot slower than a database solution. Out of curiosity why can't you use a database here? Even in in-memory one would suffice, do you not have admin access to the database? Do you not have permission to create memory tables?

Comment: I only have read permission to the database :( ... Using a static property to save that "pending for review" will work?  How about "abandoned" processes on browser ?

Comment: I wouldn't trust that all users will be running in the same application space in IIS event with static objects. you would be better off with some short of concurrency service built around a database or a singleton process like a signalR hub.  BTW, with signalR you could detect when a connection is lost and automaticly release the lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If database table is not an option, you may create an in-memory cache where you can store the Id's which are under review. Every time someone starts a review, check the memory cache to see whether the Id to be reviewed exists there or not. If not exists, Add the new id to the memory cache.(You may store a List of Ids in the memory cache).

You can use the [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx) class to achieve this.

**Remember, this is in-memory. So your App pool reset can clear the memory**. Also when you have more than one server in future, this might not work ( trouble sharing cache across servers!). In that case, you need a centralized place to keep this information. My recommendation is a db table in your sql server.

Comment: Thanks, and how the best way to control abandoned processes? User can close the browser or forget that open...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Application ?

You can make a custom class that keeps the ids of the processes and also manages the access.

Hope this helps.