# Difference between calling a web service from an ajax call and calling it from an MVC Controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 project with an OData V4 web service for the backend, and I'm starting to run into some confusion when it comes to retrieving data (not views).

I'm not sure whether I should be making my web service calls through ajax or through an MVC controller action with an HTTP client. I know you typically want some additional separation in the latter case in the sense that the controller action probably shouldn't be directly calling the web service with an HTTP client, but regardless. I should also reiterate that my question has nothing to do with Views/PartialViews; I always call a controller action to return those.

Is it only advantageous to go through a controller action when you need to perform additional work on the data being returned?

If I'm simply retrieving a list of objects from the web service, is there any point in taking that extra step by calling a controller action?

Sorry if this has been answered before. I found some vaguely similar questions but nothing too concrete.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the web service resides in a domain other than your web app domain, you probably will run into same origin policy issue when trying to make ajax call from your pages.  Basically this is not a problem, but a security feature where a web browser permits scripts contained in web page A to access data in a web page B, but only if both web pages have the same origin. An origin is defined as a combination of URI scheme, hostname, and port number.

If you have this problem, you can try to access the web service from your server code(controllers/services). This also allows you to parse the response coming back and converting to another format which your view really want. If you are accessing data which won't be changed very often, you may cache it also using [MemoryCache](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33350415/40521) or other dot net caching solutions. This will save you some network calls and improve your page load time.